# How to crash Oracle VM intentionally by loading system parameters

Tags: virtual-machines, oracle, high-load, test, stress

I am using **Oracle VM**. I want to perform a **stress test** on system parameters like CPU, RAM etc. Can anyone  help me out with the ways in which I can **load the parameters with high load** like using all the virtual cores, RAM starvation etc.

Comment: can you clarify what OS the hypervisor is on, whether you want to crash the OS with the hypervisor, or a virtual machine running through oracle VM and then what OS the virtual machine is running, and also is this on x64 or Sparc?

Comment: Hypervisor is running on Linux Server release 5.8 OS (x86_64).

I am looking for crashing the VM within some time limit.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following rb.sql script.

```
-- The Following script shows the time it takes to insert 1 million rows in a database.
-- I used it to determine that:
-- 
-- 1) Optimized Databases perform in relation to the hardware they run on,
--    and all the databases on 1 platform run within 10% of each other.
-- 2) When Rollback, Temp or Redo logs share the same underlying disks as 
--    the "alan" table, the insert takes up to twice as long.
-- 3) When the rollback segments, Temp segments or redo log buffers are > 20 meg as
--    opposed to less than 1 meg, the inserts run 2 to 5 times faster.
--    By making the log_buffer and Rollback extents sizes close to 32k, 
--    the inserts run up to 9 times slower.
set feedback off
set termout off
drop table alan;
set termout on
create table alan (name varchar2(30)) storage (initial 32k next 1m) logging noparallel storage(buffer_pool default); 
insert into alan values ('alan');
insert into alan values ('alan1');
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
insert into alan select * from alan;
set timing on
insert /*+ PPEND */ into alan logging select * from alan         /* This line shows the elapsed time. */
;
set timing off
-- select max(sequence#) from v$loghist;
set feedback on
set termout off
--drop table alan;
set termout on
```

I call it with rb16.sql:

```
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
@rb
```

And I call the rb16.sql with call_rb16.sql:

```
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
@rb16
```

Since the rb.sql script inserts into the alan table, you can make multiple oracle users and insert from multiple signons.  The rb.sql script identifies bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to just use the Linux [stress](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) utility to selectively load some or all of the system features. It's available via YUM for download...

Think of `stress` as a load-generator. Forcign the system to crash is a different effort. You can use this to see how things operate under load, but I doubt that any sane configurations from the stress utility will induce a system crash.

[image]

Also see: [Max CPU load in *nix](https://serverfault.com/questions/434908/max-cpu-load-in-nix/434914#434914)